# Definition of filtration over monoid

Tags: commutative-algebra

I want to know if the following definition is correct.

A $\textbf{filtration}$ over a monoid $M$ (operation denoted multiplicativity), is a total order $<$ on $M$ that fulfills $1_M < x$ and if $x < y$ then $ax < ay$ for any $a,x,y \in M$, together with an abelian group $A$ which has an $M$-indexed family of subgroups $(F_m(A))_{m \in M}$ such that whenever $x < y$ then $F_x(A) \subseteq F_y(A)$.

If we filter a ring $R$, then the multiplication of the ring must also be compatible with the filtration, i.e if $a \in F_x(A)$ and $b \in F_y(A)$ then $ab \in F_{xy}(A)$.

The above is what I found in my lecture notes, its the definition of a filtrered ring and abelian group. Is it correct? Is there any mistakes you can help me to point out?

Comment: It depends on what that definition is going to be used for, really...

Comment: Can you explain? How can a definition depend on what it is going to be used for, i dont get this. @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez